# Python libxml2 parsing xml having Chinese characters

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, libxml2

i encountered encoding problems when using libxml2 in python to parse Chinese charactors

```
# coding=utf8
import libxml2

def output(data):
  doc = libxml2.parseMemory(data, len(data))
  ctxt = doc.xpathNewContext()
  res_rslt = ctxt.xpathEval("/r/e/attribute::Name")
  print res_rslt[0]

data =  '''<r><e RoleID="3247" Name="中文"></e></r>'''

output(data)
```

the out put is

```
Name="&#x4E2D;&#x6587;"
```

while i'm expecting

```
Name="中文"
```

how could i make it?

Answer (score 2):

With `lxml`, things are easier and they work. It is Pythonic binding for the `libxml2` library and works wonderfully.

```
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> x = etree.fromstring('''<r><e RoleID="3247" Name="中文"></e></r>''')
>>> name = x[0].get('Name')
>>> print name
中文
```

And yes, `XPath` is also supported. The documentation is [here](http://codespeak.net/lxml/xpathxslt.html).

As for your program, have a look at this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import libxml2

def output(data):
  doc = libxml2.parseDoc(data)
  ctxt = doc.xpathNewContext()
  res_rslt = ctxt.xpathEval("/r/e/attribute::Name")
  return res_rslt[0]

data =  u'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><r><e RoleID="3247" Name="中文"></e></r>'''.encode("UTF-8")

print output(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer to these sorts of things always seems to be "use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)". And I always get upvoted for it, too (which shows, I think, that others agree with me that it's good).

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(u'''<r><e RoleID="3247" Name="中文"></e></r>''')
>>> print soup.r.e['name']
中文
```

The thing is that libxml2 is converting those characters into the proper XML entities which for XML is correct. Beautiful Soup doesn't have any such notions of feeling a need to be correct - so it just gives you what you want.

(Note in this case that using either `u'...'` or `'...'` will work; I just put it as a `unicode` because it feels better that way - whatever you do, [Beautiful Soup gives you Unicode](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#Beautiful%20Soup%20Gives%20You%20Unicode,%20Dammit).)